# How to access the built in FTP server in mac using as3

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, ftp

So I have this as3 program and I need to store some files on my server. I could have used FileReference.upload but that requires me to first use fileReference.browse , which will open a dialog box and we need to specify the location. I don't want the dialog box to open, so i can't use fileReference. I directly want the files to be saved in a directory on my server when I click a button. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

Also, I can manually access my server in mac using

```
"ftp://Admin@localhost"
```

and then i need to put my username and password. But, I don't know how to access it using as3.

Comment: A swf file is clientside like an html file.  You create a form in the swf that POST's to php, .net, etc. like a regular html form.

Comment: I was successful in connecting with the ftp server and I was able to navigate to the folder where I want to save. But when I try to upload a file, it throws a 500 Permissions denied. 
Do you know how to set permissions for the FTP server?

Comment: Sorry, no.  I haven't done that stuff for a long time.